# Hive Python UDF with argument

Tags: python, hive, user-defined-functions

I want to make hive Python UDF take constant arguments in addition to data from columns.

How can this be achieved?

In the example below, I wish hive query below be able to take the argument `'10000'`, and my_udf should be able to parse this argument `'10000'`

```
# hive>
ADD FILE my_udf.py;
SELECT TRANSFORM(col1, col2, '10000') USING 'python my_udf.py' AS (udf_output) FROM my_table;
```

and

```
# my_udf.py
import sys
for line_str in sys.stdin:
    line = line_str.strip().split('\t')
    print(line[2])  # udf outputs the constant argument we inputted: 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# hive>
ADD FILE my_udf.py;
SELECT TRANSFORM(col1, col2, '10000') USING 'python my_udf.py' AS (udf_output) FROM my_table;
```

`TRANSFORM(col1, col2, '10000')` is correct after all. I had some other syntax issues elsewhere, which caused me think this syntax didn't work.

Comment: Failed to work in some hive systems.. hmm